# Find the series $a_n$ from the given partial sum $S_n = 1/(2^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Find the series $a_n$ from the given partial sum $S_n = 1/(2^n)$.

Not sure how to go about this. I've written out the first few terms and got:
\begin{align}
S_1 &= 1/2, \\
S_2 &= 1/4 = 1/2 - 1/4, \\
S_3 &= 1/8 = 1/2 - 1/4 - 1/8, \\
\end{align}
... and so on.

So the sequence seems to be $(1/2, -1/4, -1/8, -1/16, ... -1/2^n)$

So the formula we are looking for has $f(1)=1/2$, $f(2)=-1/4$, $f(3)=-1/8$, ... and so on.

I can't figure out the formula for it. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: $a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$.

Comment: You don't need a single formula. For instance, saying $a_1 = ...$ and $a_n = ... (n \ge 2)$ also counts as a valid answer.